# Apache: override settings (like Timeout) inside a VirtualHost directive?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Is the following configuration correct ?
If not, is there any alternative ?

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.20:80>

ServerName mywebsite.fr
ServerAlias test.mywebsite.fr

Timeout 3000 # Overrides main configuration

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html

Third column on that page will tell you whether the setting(directive) you are trying to change can be specified in virtualhost or its global directive.

HTH